# log all pip commands in a given virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'd like to keep a record of all `pip` commands that were executed in a given virtual environment and of the package versions that got installed/updated/removed. Is there an easy way to do that?

Alternatively, how do I get `requirements.txt` (including `--install-option`, etc.) out of my virtual environment state, if that's possible? Presumably, only the immediate dependencies need to be there.

Comment: `pip install foo bar baz >& pip_log.txt` will log output if you're on a POSIX system.

Comment: `pip` with a requirements files is a desired state system. This makes the changes irrelevant. You should consider using a requirements files only (no manual changes) and keep a history of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `pip` script to insert this at the beginning of the `__main__` segment:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    env_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    with open(os.path.join(env_dir, 'pip_log.txt'), 'a') as f:
        f.write(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]) + '\n')
```

This will log every call to pip to `pip_log.txt` in the virtualenv directory. `Pip` is found in the bin folder in the virtualenv, next to the activate script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history command to view the history of all your commands and then grep for pip with out put to a file.
Similar to the comment above.